# What is the minimum recommended page title from an SEO perspective?

Tags: seo, title, page

What is the minimum recommended page title from an SEO perspective? Would there be any problems if I use a two words title?

I know that there is a maximum recommended, but I did not find anything about the minimum length.

Comment: See the recommended title [tips](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) from Google, noting that if it's insufficient Google: `...may try to generate an improved title from anchors, on-page text, or other sources.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short titles are okay if concise and complete. However, I have always recommended using of much of the entire real estate as possible for performance and here is what I mean.

It is rare that one or two words offer a complete title that engages a user and performs well for click-through rates (CTR). The CTR is extremely important. What would be the point of impressions if no one clicks on your link? While some recommend avoiding stop words, I say ignore that advice. The title should be conversational. For example, Chocolate Cake does not answer the question *What the page is about.* But, *How to bake a Chocolate Cake* does. That should really be the goal and not just two words that are keywords. Though lean, it may not convert well.

Titles: Use a hard limit of 55 characters. No more. For Google, if people have not noticed lately, has dropped using the ellipsis, "..." as much as they have opting for other sources for the SERP link. If your title is longer than 55 characters, then Google may ignore the title, not for ranking and indexing of course, but for the SERPs and instead look to the `h1` tag, `description` meta-tag, or just plain make one up. I noticed this starting about two-three months ago when my own titles were no longer used and Google made one up for me. It was actually good for performance to a point, but I trimmed the titles of my pages to less than 55 characters and now they are being used again. It is a short succinct conversational title and it seems to be performing much better.

While we are on the subject, do not create an exact duplicate of your `title` tag in your `h1` tag. Instead, the most recent recommendation seems to be to make an alternative title. Again less than 55 characters. This logic means that Google has two options to chose between when creating the SERP link. `H1` tags do appear in the SERPs as links from time to time. I have previously liked longer `h1` tags, but have since changed my mind.

Regarding the `description` meta-tag, limit that to about 150 characters for the same reason. Under normal circumstances, Google will use the `title` tag for the SERP link and the `description` meta-tag for the snippet. However, this may not always be the case since the snippet will likely reflect the search terms used in Google more than anything. If you find this, modify the description to reflect actual search terms used and the number of times that the `description` meta-tag is used will increase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also, what you said about using stop words in the title makes perfect sense. Thanks for the other tips as well.

Answer (score 7):

Better question would be: `Are two words a relevant pagetitle to that page?`

It's a bit minimal, but if **relevant**, it's no problem. But I dont think it can be very **relevant** with only two words.

Comment: I agree, titling a page talking about your web design services "Website Design" is relevant to the page content, but not necessarily optimized and can probably be expanded upon.

Comment: thank you . Of course this is the relevant question. For some of my pages only 2-3 words make up the most relevant title and adding more words just to make it longer would either not make sens to the content or make it look bad from a user's point of view (these particular pages ofc). But yes, you are perfectly right and thank you again

Comment: I doubt you cant make a better title than 2/3 words, but you can decide that better than I can

Answer (score 4):

From the Google's support [page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) you can find that

> Page titles should be descriptive and concise. Avoid vague descriptors
>   like "Home" for your home page, or "Profile" for a specific person's
>   profile

A title tag is the most important tag in your page. It tells
the search engines what your page is about so avoid two word title for your page. But there is no complusary minimum word limit for title tag. You can find more information about title tag [here](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2154469/How-to-Write-Title-Tags-For-Search-Engine-Optimization).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding SEO, there is no minimum size for the `<title>` tag of a page (actually yes, maybe 1 character; otherwise, you don't use it).

There are many companies which uses just a word (often a brand name) as `<title>` tag. As example, the home page of [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/home.php).

Just keep in mind the most important is your `<title>` tag must be relevant to your page. If you respect this rule, use it but don't pay attention to its size.

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster Tools likes unique page titles. For my quotation mashup I use titles like "A Quotation by Franz Kafka" so if I have two quotations by Franz Kafka Google Webmaster Tools complains but I didn't change it. I think duplicate titles are not the end of the world, I think 5 words or less is best for titles, not just for SEO but for services like Twitter.

The problem with one word titles is you're likely to confuse your reader "A Quotation by Franz Kafka" is a pretty descriptive title if I changed to "A Quotation by Franz Kafka starting with 'I believe..." that might be better but it is a bit more work for me, maybe I should consider it though. For blog posts I definitely like shorter titles you can append your blog name or company name at the end which is why keeping the actual post title short is important.

Answer (score -1):

**Use only one per page, placed within the head tag**

I have seen many pages in my reviews that have either no  tag at all, have multiple  tags in the code, or have put the  tag within the  tag instead of the  tag. All of that is wrong, and negates the potential value of the  tag.

To keep your code valid and earn the value inherent in this key HTML element, simply keep this in mind: there should only be one  tag used per page, and it should only be used within the  section of the code.

More info :

http://searchengineland.com/nine-best-practices-for-optimized-title-tags-111979

Title tag can be normally between 50-68 characters and Meta description tag can be around 140 – 150 characters.

Be Mindful of Length :

As stated above, search engines will truncate titles in search results that exceed a certain length. For Google, this length is usually between 50-60 characters, or 512 pixels wide. If the title is too long, engines will show an ellipsis, "..." to indicate that a title tag has been cut off. That said, length is not a hard and fast rule. Longer titles often work better for social sharing, and many SEOs believe search engines may use the keywords in your title tag for ranking purposes, even if those keywords get cut off in search results. In the end, it's usually better to write a great title that converts and get clicks than it is to obsess over length.

Comment: Though this might be relevant to read, this doesn't answer anything about the minimum, as TS asks