# RSS Feed / HTML Title and Dscription Limit Per SEO Standard

Tags: seo, rss

I'm creating an RSS feed which is meant to be SEO friendly in the invent the content is syndicated and created as a webpage.

I'm under the impression currently that this is the going standard:

Title: 80 Characters
Description: 160 Characters

But I suspect this is either outdated or wrong.

What is the standard Title and Description limit?

Comment: Are you primarily talking about the title tag and the description meta-tag? If so, this answer has the answer for you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61432/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-page-title-from-an-seo-perspective/61454#61454 As a modifier, read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69050/my-title-tag-doesnt-appear-to-be-getting-crawled-by-google-properly/69080#69080 Ignore the titles.

Comment: To be clear. There is no standard for this but there is a typical limit.

Comment: Do you ask about length limits specified in the feed standard? If yes, which feed format are you referring to? (there are several different standards named "RSS")